# Problems with NDSolve and initial conditions (NDSolve::nbnum1:)

Tags: differential-equations, sow-reap

this is the situation, I'm trying to solve a system (s1) with two differential equations, called "x[Ne]" and "y[Ne]". They have and initial condition that first need to satisfy another NDSolve for "phi[NN]". Since I put this as initial condition, problemas like NDSolve::nbnum1:, NDSolve::ecboo:, appears, and I honestly don't understand why. Before I put this initial condition starting from "phi[NN]", the system for "x[Ne]" and "y[Ne]" has initial condition "x[0]==x0, y[0]==y0", where "x0" and "y0" was free parameters and no solutions coming from the differential equation for "phi[NN]", and I didn't get any trouble. Any kind of idea with these situations? I read about "reap" and "sow" but i didn't understand how to stick with my code:

```
"condition for x0";
Sol\[Phi]f[\[Delta]_, \[Xi]_, n_] := 
 FindRoot[(\[Phi]f^(-2 - n/
     2) (-1 + Sqrt[
      1 + 4 \[Delta] \[Phi]f^(-1 + 
         n) (-4 + n + 8/(2 + \[Xi] \[Phi]f^2))]))/(2 \[Delta]) == 
   1, {\[Phi]f, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]
\[Phi]f[\[Delta]_, \[Xi]_, n_] := \[Phi]f /. 
  Sol\[Phi]f[\[Delta], \[Xi], n]

sr[\[Delta]_, \[Xi]_, n_] := 
 NDSolve[{Derivative[1][\[Phi]][
     NN] == (\[Phi][
      NN]^-n (2 + \[Xi] *\[Phi][NN]^2) (-1 + Sqrt[
       1 + 4 \[Delta]*\[Phi][NN]^(-1 + 
          n) *(-4 + n + 8/(2 + \[Xi] *\[Phi][NN]^2))]))/(
    4 \[Delta]), \[Phi][0] == \[Phi]f[\[Delta], \[Xi], 
     n]}, \[Phi], {NN, 0, 70}, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]

xCMBsr[\[Delta]_, \[Xi]_, NN_] := \[Phi][NN] /. sr[\[Delta], \[Xi], 2]
Vo[\[Delta]_, \[Xi]_, NN_, 
  n_, \[Lambda]_] := (\[Pi]^2 \[Lambda] xCMBsr[\[Delta], \[Xi], 
     NN]^(-3 n) (2 + \[Xi] xCMBsr[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN]^2)^3 (-1 + 
      Sqrt[1 + 
       4 \[Delta] xCMBsr[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN]^(-1 + 
         n) (-4 + n + 8/(
          2 + \[Xi] xCMBsr[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN]^2))])^2 (1 + 
      2 Sqrt[1 + 
        4 \[Delta] xCMBsr[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN]^(-1 + 
          n) (-4 + n + 8/(
           2 + \[Xi] xCMBsr[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN]^2))])^(3/2))/(8 Sqrt[
    3] \[Delta]^2 (1 + 
      4 \[Delta] xCMBsr[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN]^(-1 + 
        n) (-4 + n + 8/(2 + \[Xi] xCMBsr[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN]^2)))^(
    1/4))
"condition for y0";
y0[\[Delta]_, \[Xi]_, NN_, n_, \[Lambda]_] := 
  PowerExpand[
    1/(2 Sqrt[6] \[Delta]) xCMBsr[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN]^(-n/2) Sqrt[
     2 + \[Xi] xCMBsr[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN]^2]*Sqrt[
     Vo[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, 
      n, \[Lambda]]] (1 - 
       1 Sqrt[1 + 
         4 \[Delta] xCMBsr[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN]^(-1 + 
           n) (-4 + n + 8/(
            2 + \[Xi] xCMBsr[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN]^2))])] // 
   FullSimplify;
\[Alpha][\[Delta]_, \[Xi]_, NN_, n_, \[Lambda]_] :=  (\[Delta]^(1/3))/
  Vo[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, n, \[Lambda]]^(1/3);
"system i want to solve";
s1[\[Delta]_, \[Xi]_, NN_, n_, \[Lambda]_] := 
 NDSolve[{Derivative[1][x][
     Ne] == -((3 (2 + \[Xi] x[Ne]^2) y[Ne])/(3 \[Xi] x[Ne] y[Ne] + 
         3 \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, n, \[Lambda]] y[Ne]^3 - 
         Sqrt[3] \[Sqrt]((2 + \[Xi] x[Ne]^2) (2 Vo[\[Delta], \[Xi], 
                  NN, n, \[Lambda]] \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, 
                  n, \[Lambda]]^2 x[Ne]^2 + y[Ne]^2) + 
             3 (\[Xi] x[Ne] y[Ne] + \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, 
                  n, \[Lambda]] y[Ne]^3)^2))), 
   Derivative[1][y][
     Ne] == -((3 (2 Vo[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, 
             n, \[Lambda]] \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, 
             n, \[Lambda]]^2 x[Ne] (2 + \[Xi] x[Ne]^2)^2 + 
           3 y[Ne] (\[Xi] x[Ne] + \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, 
                n, \[Lambda]] y[Ne]^2)^2 (-3 \[Xi] x[Ne] y[Ne] - 
              3 \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, n, \[Lambda]] y[Ne]^3 + 
              Sqrt[3] \[Sqrt]((2 + \[Xi] x[
                    Ne]^2) (2 Vo[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, 
                    n, \[Lambda]] \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, 
                    n, \[Lambda]]^2 x[Ne]^2 + y[Ne]^2) + 
                  3 (\[Xi] x[Ne] y[Ne] + \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN,
                     n, \[Lambda]] y[Ne]^3)^2)) + 
           2 (1 + 1/
               2 \[Xi] x[Ne]^2) (-4 Vo[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, 
                n, \[Lambda]] \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, 
                n, \[Lambda]]^2 \[Xi] x[Ne]^3 + 
              x[Ne] (\[Xi] (-2 + 3 \[Xi]) - 
                 6 Vo[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, 
                   n, \[Lambda]] \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, 
                   n, \[Lambda]]^3 x[Ne]) y[Ne]^2 + 
              3 \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, 
                n, \[Lambda]] (-1 + \[Xi]) y[Ne]^4 + 
              Sqrt[3] y[
                Ne] \[Sqrt]((2 + \[Xi] x[Ne]^2) (2 Vo[\[Delta], \[Xi],
                     NN, n, \[Lambda]] \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, 
                    n, \[Lambda]]^2 x[Ne]^2 + y[Ne]^2) + 
                  3 (\[Xi] x[Ne] y[Ne] + \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN,
                     n, \[Lambda]] y[Ne]^3)^2))))/((-3 \[Xi] x[Ne] y[
             Ne] - 3 \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, n, \[Lambda]] y[
             Ne]^3 + 
           Sqrt[3] \[Sqrt]((2 + \[Xi] x[Ne]^2) (2 Vo[\[Delta], \[Xi], 
                    NN, n, \[Lambda]] \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, 
                    n, \[Lambda]]^2 x[Ne]^2 + y[Ne]^2) + 
               3 (\[Xi] x[Ne] y[Ne] + \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, 
                    n, \[Lambda]] y[Ne]^3)^2)) (2 + \[Xi] x[Ne]^2 + 
           3 (\[Xi] x[Ne] + \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, 
                n, \[Lambda]] y[Ne]^2) (\[Xi] x[Ne] + 
              
              3 \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, n, \[Lambda]] y[
                Ne]^2) - 
           2 Sqrt[3] \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, n, \[Lambda]] y[
             Ne] \[Sqrt]((2 + \[Xi] x[Ne]^2) (2 Vo[\[Delta], \[Xi], 
                    NN, n, \[Lambda]] \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, 
                    n, \[Lambda]]^2 x[Ne]^2 + y[Ne]^2) + 
               3 (\[Xi] x[Ne] y[Ne] + \[Alpha][\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, 
                    n, \[Lambda]] y[Ne]^3)^2)))), 
   x[0] == xCMBsr[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN], 
   y[0] == y0[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, n, \[Lambda]]}, {x, y}, {Ne, 0, 
   70}, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]
```

Comment: Can you give numerical values for the parameters.

Comment: Of course! try this, Evaluate[{Re[x[60]]} /. s1[10^-5, 2.25*10^-3, 60, 2, 2.169*10^-9]], where x[Ne] is evaluated with s1[\[Delta], \[Xi], NN, n, \[Lambda]]

Comment: Sorry, when I evaluate "Evaluate[{Re[x[60]]} /. s1[10^-5, 2.25*10^-3, 60, 2, 2.169*10^-9]]" I get a mass of error messages.